# Clear-Site-Data header error in Chrome console

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, response-headers

I'm trying to implement a cache clearing button for our website that will append the Clear-Site-Data header on a specific route so we can be relatively sure that the users are getting the latest javascript, css, etc. after a release.  I'm assigning the header in my ActionMethod like so:
[image]

According to developer tools, I'm getting the header on the client:

[image]

So, Chrome is trying to do what I'm asking but it's throwing an error saying the types I'm passing it are unrecognized:
[image: console error when loading page with Clear-Site-Data header]

Am I missing something with how I'm creating the header?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, so here we are a few months down the road and I finally remembered to come back and post the working solution.  What I didn't understand at the time I asked the question was that the quotes are expected to be treated as literal in the response header examples I found.  So the code I posted in my question was missing a few \ characters in the strings.  What ended up working was this:

[image]

The headers on the client now look like this (note the quotes around cache and storage):

[image]

And the cache and localStorage are cleared as desired.  Hope this helps someone else as well!

Comment: I just kept experimenting and looking for examples of actual sites that used it.  A friend used it on one of his sites and when I inspected the response from his in Chrome Tools I saw that cache had double quotes around it in the inspector for his but not mine.  That's when I realized that the quotes were part of the header and not just signifying that cache was supposed to be a string.

Comment: It's interesting that there doesn't seem to be a standard for how the entries are formatted (that I could find).  In the screenshot above, Cache-Control has no quotes around its values, Clear-Site-Data does.  I wonder if someone could comment on why that is?  I was unable to find a guide for properly formatting values but to be honest, I stopped looking when I found the solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: Will it work for safari browser?

Comment: We don't develop against Safari (controlled corporate environment where Chromium based browsers are required).  I haven't tested it against Safari.  It works in Chrome, Edge and Firefox though.  Give it a shot!