# Chrome : Hard reload images

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

To hard refresh cached images I have tried multiple ways:
like clearing `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. Sending the `Clear-Site-Data` header also not clear cached images from the browser.

`location.reload(true);`//is now deprectaed
which is also not helping here

But no luck, I'm still getting old images.

I want to achieve chrome's "Empty cache and Hard Reload" feature.

I don't want to go with making the image URL unique, as it's referred from 50+ places.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear the cache in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Comment: No @Justinas above question is not resolving my issue.

Comment: @Jax-p I don't want to disable caching

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Cache.delete() Web API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete

This sample code may delete all cached items. Give it a try

```
caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
  cache.keys().then(function(keys) {
    keys.forEach(function(request, index, array) {
      cache.delete(request);
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: I added sample code from here but didn't try it myself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/keys

Comment: This also doesn't help:`caches.keys().then((keyList) => Promise.all(keyList.map((key) => caches.delete(key))))`

Comment: I found another way that may clear the cache, cookies etc.  When delivered with a response from https://example.com/clear, the following header will cause all cookies, caches, and DOM-accessible storage associated with the origin https://example.com to be cleared, as well as execution contexts for the same origin to be neutered and reloaded:
Clear-Site-Data: "*"     https://www.w3.org/TR/clear-site-data/

Comment: Hi @ozgur I have tried `Clear-Site-Data` header too but no luck

Comment: @Kanti, I'm sorry I'm out of ideas

Comment: Finally `"Clear-Site-Data": "cache"` header has worked, previously I passed `cache` without  double-quote, I have found this answer helpful, but because of VPN it was not showing images and the answer is in image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185821/clear-site-data-header-error-in-chrome-console#answer-55142501

Comment: Can the Clear-Site-Data header be included somehow in the HTML source of a web page?